# Microsoft Teams change message feed direction in my teams

Tags: microsoft-teams

I've been using Microsoft teams for a while now and one day the feed in my teams was upside down. I guess this is some new ux improvement but it's very confusing and irritating.

From what I've been able to tell there is no option to revert the change in settings. At the moment when I start typing my messages I have to do it from the top with a feed that goes from newest at the top and oldest further down. Anyone knows if I'm able to change the feed direction in my teams to what it used to be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Top-down channels are part of "the new Teams" desktop client, and there are currently **no** settings to change the top-down feed direction. See the MS Teams Community request about this [here](https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/idea/fd7275b6-46ca-ed11-a81b-000d3a0450e3).

That said, you may be able to switch back to the Classic Teams by turning off the New Teams toggle at the top of Teams. per the [MS Support Site](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/try-the-new-microsoft-teams-2d4a0c96-fa52-43f8-a006-4bfbc62cf6c5#:%7E:text=Switch%20back%20to%20classic%20Teams&text=To%20switch%20back%20to%20the,or%20meeting%20will%20be%20disconnected.):

[image: screenshot]

Though this might only be a Preview version feature? Another alternative is the web client, since channels are also still top-down there.

Comment: I acually dont have new teams toggled on and still have this issue. Thanks for your suggestion with the web client, i'l stick with that for now.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like Teams have implemented this feature and you can change the direction by clicking on the three dots in the top right corner.

[image]